# What does the "ONET" in ONET.xml stand for?

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint, a file named ONET.xml is usually needed when creating a custom site definition. Out of curiosity, does anyone know what ONET stands for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stands for Office Net.

[per this blog entry.](http://greggalipeau.wordpress.com/category/sharepoint/wspbuilder/)

> On a side note: I heard that Onet stands for Office Net.